# Look back through a row and find the last time I wrote a particular word

Tags: excel-2007

I have a table that I am creating in relation to toolhire and I have many columns for on hire / off hire / days utilised. in the columns next to the on hire and off hire dates, I have it set to write the words `ON` and `OFF` when a date is entered into that cell. I want to set up a column at the end of the table which will look back through the row and tell me whether the item is currently ON or OFF by finding whether the last word it finds is `ON` or `OFF`.

Answer (score 0):

If a row spans ColumnsA:M say, and contains only blanks, numeric values or `ON` or `OFF` then please try, say in ColumnN and for Row2:

```
=INDEX(A2:M2,MATCH("zzz",A2:M2))
```